# It is possible to modify a form control value inside a Cypress Angular e2e test?

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, form-control

I need to modify the Form Control Value inside a Angular Cypress e2e test

It is possible to modify without using something like:

```
cy.getByTestId("custom-test-id").find("input").type("value", { force: true } )
```

Comment: What kind of input are you using?

Comment: it is a custom component extending `ngx-daterangepicker-material` with the input in readonly mode and not possible to test interacting with the calendar. I need to bypass the interaction with the component and use the native Form Control value.

Comment: Cypress is meant to behave like a real user would, so IMO it goes against it's definition to try to tweak form values directly rather than interacting with the UI inside a Cypress test. Can you provide more information and what are you trying to test and which problems you are having? Maybe we can find another way.